# Adding a column into table in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

Add a column named flag into table with default value 0 and then copy all the rows of the table and change the flag to 1 for only the rows that we just copied.

```
Table A

Name     Flag
apple      0
banana     0
orange     0

After Copying the rows
Name     Flag
apple     0
apple     0
banana    0
banana    0
orange    0
orange    0

Now change the flag to 1 to copied rows
Name     Flag
apple     0
apple     1
banana    0
banana    1
orange    0
orange    1
```

I was able to do this by creating a temp table but is there any other way to do it without creating temp table in the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the original table:

```
SQL> select * from tablea order by name;

NAME
------
apple
banana
orange
```

Add a new column - `flag`, its default value is `0`:

```
SQL> alter table tablea add flag number(1) default 0;

Table altered.
```

After that, table's contents is:

```
SQL> select * From tablea order by name;

NAME         FLAG
------ ----------
apple           0
banana          0
orange          0
```

Insert "duplicates", but flag will now be `1`:

```
SQL> insert into tablea (name, flag)
  2  select name, 1 from tablea;

3 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From tablea order by name, flag;

NAME         FLAG
------ ----------
apple           0
apple           1
banana          0
banana          1
orange          0
orange          1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```